# A future in mathematics

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, education

I am a Junior in high school right now, trying to figure out what to do next mathematically.  I have familiarity with real analysis (Baby Rudin, and also a bit on the gauge integral), complex analysis (mostly contour integration), and am building a good algebra background (from Birkhoff, with help from Dummit and Foote).  I also have familiarity with many disparate topics (e.g. Fractional calculus, and elliptic curves).  I'm interested in studying...everything really, but I am currently trending towards algebraic geometry, after burning out a bit on analysis (I went from Calc AB through Rudin and beyond in the summer).  My problem is that I haven't really had guidance since auditing Differential Equations and Calc 3 over the summer, other than answers to elliptic curve questions from a prof at a semi-local university (there is nothing within an hour of me).  I've emailed a few professors at big universities, but so far response has been lukewarm (mostly due to time constraints for them).  I was hoping someone on this site, which I've sort of used as a teacher, could point me somewhere productive.  Maybe a math department that might be receptive, or a guide on what other topics to study in order to give myself a proper maths background?  Thanks in advance! (Also, I understand that this should probably be a community wiki, but don't know how to make it one).

Comment: Continuing: [Here](http://www.ams.org/profession/prizes-awards/ams-awards/epsilon-award) is a list of summer programs to which the AMS gives grants; deadlines are coming up. I know for a fact that Ross is excellent but I'm sure they're all good. The people involved try to keep student costs down and in many cases offer financial support. There are hundreds of lists of "books to study", even specific to algebraic geometry, online and I'm just not sure how much a few more in the answers below will really help you; I'm not confident that the answer lies in books at all.

Comment: Dear Gotthold, may I ask you how old  you are? I'm asking because I'm not familiar with the American school system and I'm not sure what Junior high-school corresponds to.

Comment: Dear Elencwajg, I am 16.

Comment: I can’t speak to the present version, but the Ross program that @Hoot singled out was certainly outstanding when I attended back in $1963$, the last year that it was at Notre Dame.

Comment: I would be happy to try to answer your questions.  Click on my name, and you will get my email address.  (I don't know about elliptic curves though.)  Also, have you tried the chat rooms on this website?